# talking sexual stuff online

Tags: nikah

i have an online boyfriend and we both love eachother a lot, we met on a game, we both are determined to meet eachother irl and get a nikkah, but recently we have been talking abkut sexual stuff and how good it would feel in real life, which we also say we would do after nikkah, how bad is this as we are not acting upon it, and we try too stop but talking about  it just gives us too much happiness